# Information isn't updating & tracing

Tags: php, database, module

When submitting my form that stores my `facebook id` it is sent to the method `save_settings()`. No matter what I do I can't dump variables or echo them out to see what is being sent, so I think this is because it's not actually getting to the method for whatever reason. My form action params are:

```
index.php?S=32016fcb4a352c152f953d5a97d8efb6a290edfc&D=cp&&method=save_settings&method=save_settings
```

I'm wondering if having the double `&&` is an issue. Here are my URL vars controlling this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->_base_url = BASE . AMP . 'C=addons_modules'.AMP.'M=show_module_cp'.AMP.'module=facebook_photos';
        $this->EE->load->helper('text');        
    }
```

And here is the form variable sent to the form

```
$data = array(
        'form_action' => $this->base_url . AMP . 'method=save_settings',
        'facebook_id' => $results->setting_value
    );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I found a lot of issues in my code. I was referencing base_url instead of _base_url. Added in the method twice. Now that I have it submitting to the right place I'm getting the following error: `Disallowed Key Characters.`

Comment: Can you post your "Disallowed Key Characters" issue as a new question? It will get better attention. Also, make sure to accept your answer as the "correct" one by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: My disallowed key characters issue actually came from the double `&&` in the URL. Do you still think it's worth a new question?

Comment: If you need help finding a solution, yes post a new question. Your question here has been answered so this to me is a new question. Your comment will get lost here. Provide code samples as needed with the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured out the issues, my `form_action` variable was linking to `$this->base_url` instead of `$this->_base_url` that I had set at the beginning. This then sent the POST information to the correct path.

Then I was able to troubleshoot the PHP like I normally would by dumping variables out to see why the redirect wasn't working. The redirect wasn't working because of the necessary `AMP` after `BASE`.

Finally the database is updating as I put the full table name of `exp_fb_photo_settings` vs `fb_photo_settings` I was using in the dbforge function on the install script.

Thanks.